# Skip/Ignore values with maximum difference more than 1 between successive vector from a large array in matlab

Tags: matlab

Given the following array:

```
[158 159 159 160 162 163 161 162 162 168 169 163 164 164 165 171 177 178 166 167]
```

How can I quickly recreate an array which keeps the same order but skips values with the maximum difference more than 1 between successive vector?

The desired result is:

```
[158 159 159 160 161 162 162 163 164 164 165 166 167]
```

Comment: Please, add code that you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A= [158 159 159 160 162 163 161 162 162 168 169 163 164 164 165 171 177 178 166 167];

for i=2:length(A)
    if i>length(A)
        break
    end
    while abs(A(i)-A(i-1))>1
        A(i) = [];
    end
end
```

- The starting `length(A)` is 20 but it will be shorten. Hence, I have to check the condition and `break` the loop if needed.
- I use `while` instead of `if` to check whether the successive element. For example, I check the difference between 160 and 162, then 162 was deleted. Then I need to keep check the difference between 160 and 163.

Comment: There is a bug.
If you change the array `A` with `A = 1:2:100` you will receive the error `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive solution:

```
a= [158 159 159 160 162 163 161 162 162 168 169 163 164 164 165 171 177 178 166 167];
ii=1;
while true
    l= length(a);
    csa = circshift(a,1);
    csa(1)=NaN;
    a( a - csa >1 ) = [];

    if l == length(a)
        break;
    end
end
disp(a)
```

`a` is the input array modified by the algorithm.
If you run it, the result is:

```
a = [158   159   159   160   161   162   162   163   164   164   165   166   167]
```

as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`diff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) along with [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7ekiy-1):

```
a = [158 159 159 160 162 163 161 162 162 168 169 163 164 164 165 171 177 178 166 167];

test = [false diff(a)>1];
while any(test)
    a = a(~test);
    test = [false diff(a)>1];
end
```

Which returns:

```
a =

   158   159   159   160   161   162   162   163   164   164   165   166   167
```

Comment: You should have better performances on longer arrays if `test` is a logical array. The line `test = [0 diff(a)>1];` should be changed to `test = [false diff(a)>1];`

Comment: Thank you for giving me hint but still, I am getting an error when I am using a large array in which the number of the element is 1536. The error is: Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Comment: You probably have a column vector and not a row vector. Try `test = [false; diff(a)>1];` instead.